# Dont have access to Gmail

Tags: gmail

I am an SD and one of our users is having this problem with gmail.

He has no issues with accessing GCP and analytics but eveytime he tries to access mail.google.com, he immediately gets this error message.

We are sorry, but you do not have access to Gmail. Please contact your organisation administrator for access.

Even his Manage google account dropdown doesnt show the icon for mail.

We had contacted the team that provisions the GCP access and they said that it is not under their scope.

Comment: https://admin.google.com/ - Directory > Users. Click into the user in question, scroll down to where it says "Apps".